# My image with min height cant be zoomed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
/*
* rwdImageMaps jQuery plugin v1.5
*
* Allows image maps to be used in a responsive design by recalculating the area coordinates to match the actual image size on load and window.resize
*
* Copyright (c) 2013 Matt Stow
* https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps
* http://mattstow.com
* Licensed under the MIT license
*/
;(function(a){a.fn.rwdImageMaps=function(){var c=this;var b=function(){c.each(function(){if(typeof(a(this).attr("usemap"))=="undefined"){return}var e=this,d=a(e);a("<img />").load(function(){var g="width",m="height",n=d.attr(g),j=d.attr(m);if(!n||!j){var o=new Image();o.src=d.attr("src");if(!n){n=o.width}if(!j){j=o.height}}var f=d.width()/100,k=d.height()/100,i=d.attr("usemap").replace("#",""),l="coords";a('map[name="'+i+'"]').find("area").each(function(){var r=a(this);if(!r.data(l)){r.data(l,r.attr(l))}var q=r.data(l).split(","),p=new Array(q.length);for(var h=0;h<p.length;++h){if(h%2===0){p[h]=parseInt(((q[h]/n)*100)*f)}else{p[h]=parseInt(((q[h]/j)*100)*k)}}r.attr(l,p.toString())})}).attr("src",d.attr("src"))})};a(window).resize(b).trigger("resize");return this}})(jQuery);
```

```html
<HEAD>
 <title> Nicolas Marin: Pagina principal</title>
 <style>
 img[usemap]{
 min-width: 100vmin;
 max-height: 75vw;
 height: 100vmin;
 width: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
 }
 </style>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
 <map name="mapa">
 <area shape="rect" alt="Salidas" title="" coords="726,356,932,434" href="https://picasaweb.google.com/nicolas.marin" target="" />
 <area shape="rect" alt="Relatos" title="" coords="726,473,933,552" href="relatos.htm" target="" />
 <area shape="rect" alt="Otros" title="" coords="725,591,930,669" href="otros.htm" target="" />
 <area shape="rect" alt="Más Diseños" title="" coords="414,591,622,671" href="mas_disenos.htm" target="" />
 <area shape="rect" alt="Esquemas" title="" coords="413,473,623,552" href="esquemas.htm" target="" />
 <area shape="rect" alt="Tablas" title="" coords="412,355,624,439" href="tablas.htm" target="" />
 <area shape="rect" alt="Libros" title="" coords="96,355,304,434" href="libros.htm" target="" />
 <area shape="rect" alt="Artículos" title="" coords="96,470,304,553" href="articulos.htm" target="" />
 <area shape="rect" alt="Docente" title="" coords="97,591,303,670" href="docente.htm" target="" />
 <area shape="rect" alt="Banner" title="" coords="24,32,930,149" href="personal.htm" target="" /></map>
 

 <body style="background-color:#BDBDBD">
 
  <img src="Diapositiva1.PNG" usemap="#mapa", border="0">
 
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery.rwdImageMaps.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
   $('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();
  });
 </script>
</BODY>
```

Ive got a web based on a lone image with an image map that resize trough a jquery script, with the intention of keeping the image full screen but with no deforming (aka: stretching the image to the screen keeping aspect ratio) I used some min-width and max-height using vmin and vmax values, that adjust the image to the screen exactly the way I want but dont let me zoom in or out and thats my problem.

¿How can I bypass this problem to be able of zoom in the page? or in other instance ¿is there any other way to resize the image full screen, aspect ratio and functioning with the image map resizer?

thanks anyone, this is my css for the image:

```
img[usemap]{
min-width: 100vmin;
max-height: 75vw;
height: 100vmin;
width: auto;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
margin: auto;
overflow: auto;
position: fixed;
right: 0;
top: 0;
}
```

Im using the image map resizer from: https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps

Thanks to everyone and have a nice day!

Comment: example of *your code* please with the image map resizer integrated (jsfiddle or something)

Comment: i think its done, any suggest?

thanks for answer